# How to Access inner list item in c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am working on windows phone app using c# language and I am facing issue to access inner list item in c#.

I have following json class

```
public List<List<string>> Professions { get; set; }
```

code for getting response from Json web service

```
list_professions.ItemsSource = rootObject.result.Professions;
```

UI

```
<phone:LongListSelector Name="list_professions" Tap="list_professions_Tap"  
    IsGroupingEnabled="True">

</phone:LongListSelector>
```

JSON Response Like

```
{"flag":"1","message":"Result Found","result":{"Professions":[["Abortion Services","Abortion Counsellor","Abortion Clinic"],["Access Consultant","Access Control Systems","Access Equipment","Designer","dshajkfhksdajkfhafkdjsh","hjkrty"],["Accident Claims"],["Accountant","Book-Keeping","Auditing","VAT Returns","Business Advice","Payroll","test","First Custom Service"],["Acoustic Services"],["Acturary","Risk Assessor"],["Acupunctur","Herbal Remedies","Massage","Healing","Accupressure"],["Addiction Counsellor","Alcohol Addiction","Drug Addiction","Counselling","Psychotherapy"],["Adhesive Products"],["Adoption & Fostering"],["Adult Education Centres","Adult Tuition","Private Tuition","ESL","Home Tuition"],["Advertising Services","Advertising Agency","Marketing Services","Online Marketing","Press Marketing"],["Aerials","Satellite Dishes","Cable TV"],["Aeronautical Instruments"],["Aerosols"],["After School Care"],["Agricultural Services","Agricultural Vehicles"],["Air Compressors"],["Air Conditioning Services","Heating Services","Air Purification Equipment"]]}}
```

Comment: Can you show your json response at least?

Comment: You're saying you're facing an issue, but not telling what the actual issue is

Comment: Coder1409 sir please check json response.

Comment: KooKiz sir read the question carefully i have describe all the issue

Comment: @user No you haven't. "I am facing issue to access inner list item" doesn't tell us anything. Tell us what you expect and what you got instead.

Comment: BCdotWEB sir i Means each index of outer List contain a List of strings. As List[0] = List<string> now i want to access inner list item

Comment: Your **List<List<string>>** like is array of arrays, to get inner element use double index **Professions[index1][index2]** and you'll get a single string. If you need to represent one instance of **List<string>** in LongListSelector, then you need to create appropriate **DataTemplate** for LongListSelector.

Comment: Hello 14shm4n  sir i want when user tap a particular item in LongListSelector how i can get that related item suppose i have List[0]=lIst[0]"a"
          =list[1]"b"

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply asking for this ?

```
var firstItemOfProfession0 = (Professions[0])[0];
```

use a double foreach if you want to loop through

```
foreach(var profession in Professions)
{
  foreach(var subProfession in profession)
  {
    Console.Writeline(subProfession);
  }
}
```

if you need to have a flatten list use Linq:

```
var flattenProfessions = Professions.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```